# Function to Increment Integers in a Table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have an Update statement where it recognizes duplicate values in one field and for each one found I want to increment the time up by one minute in a date/time field. I can't change the duplicate value because it breaks other parts of the project.

My code is currently:

```
UPDATE table
SET Date = GETDATE()
Where Seq in (Select Seq from table 
Group By Seq
Having COUNT(Seq) > 1)
```

Currently it sets all the dates to the same time. How would I set the Date so that each gets a unique time?

I tried something like:

```
SET Date = DATEADD(Mi,1, Date)
```

This increments up by 1 minute on all records. How do I touch them all separately?

Comment: are you using MSSQL / ORACLE / mySql?

Comment: MSSQL - I thought I tagged sql-server

Answer (score 3):

You can use `ROW_NUMBER` in a `CTE`:

```
WITH CTE AS(
    SELECT *,
        rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY(SELECT NULL))
    FROM Seq
    WHERE Seq IN(SELECT Seq FROM Seq GROUP BY Seq HAVING COUNT(Seq) > 1)
)
UPDATE CTE
    SET Date = DATEADD(MINUTE, rn, GETDATE())
```

Comment: This worked in a test environment. I'm cautious to use it on live data. But life is all about taking risks.

Comment: Make sure to backup your data.

Comment: Is there a way to increment just by 1 rather than by the number of rows in the table? The incoming data feed might change in size (as newer data comes in but the duplicates don't drop off for a couple days) while the number of duplicates will be static.

Comment: You could add `PARTITION BY Seq` in the `ROW_NUMBER`.

Comment: `rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Seq ORDER BY(SELECT NULL))`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
UPDATE table
SET Date = DATEADD(Mi,1, Date)
Where ROWID in (Select MIN(t.ROWID) from table t
Group By Seq
Having COUNT(Seq) > 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Another approach using `RANK` and `ROW_NUMBER` to derive the numberof minutes to add to each Date in the group (if I've interpreted your question correctly).

Should work on 2012 up (you don't mention which version of SQL Server you're using)

```
CREATE TABLE #Seq(seq INT,date DATETIME2);

DECLARE @Now DATETIME2 = SYSDATETIME();

INSERT INTO #Seq
    ( seq, date )
VALUES 
     (0, DATEADD(MINUTE, 1, @Now))
    ,(0, DATEADD(MINUTE, 2, @Now))
    ,(0, DATEADD(MINUTE, 3, @Now))
    ,(1, DATEADD(MINUTE, 10, @Now))
    ,(1, DATEADD(MINUTE, 10, @Now))
    ,(1, DATEADD(MINUTE, 10, @Now))
    ,(2, DATEADD(MINUTE, 20, @Now))
    ,(2, DATEADD(MINUTE, 21, @Now))
    ,(2, DATEADD(MINUTE, 22, @Now));

SELECT * FROM #Seq;

WITH CTE AS(
SELECT 
    SEQ
    ,Date
    ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY seq ORDER BY Date) rn
    ,RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY seq ORDER BY Date) rnk
FROM #seq
)
UPDATE CTE  SET Date = DATEADD(MINUTE, (rn-rnk), Date);

SELECT * FROM #Seq;
```